# cv2.threshold transforming cells that it shouldn't

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In the code below I have a numpy array of 8-bit integers. I want to apply a threshold to them so I call `cv2.threshold(img,128,1,cv2.THRSH_TOZERO)[1]`.The docs indicate that the function should return an array that has a value of `0` in every cell that was less than `128`, and the original value in every cell that was greater than or equal to `128`.

What's weirder, is that it appears that `cv2.threshold` behaved differently for identical values in different cells.

```
In [48]:img
Out[48]: 
array([[128, 128, 128, ..., 133, 133, 133],
       [128, 128, 128, ..., 134, 134, 134],
       [128, 128, 128, ..., 136, 136, 136],
       ..., 
       [132, 132, 132, ..., 128, 128, 128],
       [132, 132, 132, ..., 128, 128, 128],
       [132, 132, 132, ..., 128, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8)

In [49]:imgThresh=cv2.threshold(img,128,1,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)[1]

In[50]:imgThresh
Out[50]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133],
       ..., 
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 151, 133]], dtype=uint8)
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this kind of behavior?

EDIT:
I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 and followed the install directions from the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)
Also, per request, I'm adding a more simplified modification... which appears to be working. Not sure what to make of that
    In[1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html):import numpy, cv2

```
In[2]:img=numpy.random.randint(0,255,(100,100)).astype(numpy.uint8)



In[3]:img
Out[3]: 
array([[122, 192, 125, ..., 224, 138, 157],
       [ 46,  90,  33, ...,  95, 251,  24],
       [238,  87, 113, ...,  60, 190, 175],
       ..., 
       [ 30,  33, 100, ..., 182, 123,  79],
       [ 84, 180,  34, ...,  37,  52, 194],
       [ 94,  51,  96, ..., 243,  69, 241]], dtype=uint8)

In[4]:img1=cv2.threshold(img,244,1,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
In[5]:
Out[5]:
(244.0,
 array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 251,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ..., 
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current version and as far as I know in some of the recent versions it returns

- img(x,y), if img(x,y)>thresh
- 0, otherwise

[OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold)

So if you do a `cv2.threshold(img,128,1,cv2.THRSH_TOZERO)` all your values of 128 will be set to 0. If you want them to stay at 128 use `cv2.threshold(img,129,1,cv2.THRSH_TOZERO)`.

The fact that you get different values for the same inputs could imply that your installation is broken. How did you install OpenCV and what OS? What version do you use? Have you tried a c version of the code?

I tried to reproduce your error with the following code. And for me everything is fine. Could you try the following code and post your outputs.

```
import numpy,cv2
img=numpy.random.randint(0,255,(100,100)).astype(numpy.uint8)
img1=cv2.threshold(img,128,1,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
```

Comment: I've done as you ask and, interestingly, thresh is performing as it should. I have not tried a C version of the code (not familiar with C). I suppose I could reinstall and see if it still happens